# How to solve Auth0 Callback URL error in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0, callbackurl

I'm using Auth0 with React Native. I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0). I'm running the following code:

```
auth0.webAuth.authorize({
  scope: 'openid email',
  audience: '{MY_DOMAIN}'
})
```

where {YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN} is replaced with my actual Auth0 domain.

I've added `{YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}://${YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}/ios/{YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}/callback`, where I've replaced `{YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}` and `{YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}` with the corresponding values, to my list of "Allowed Callback URLs" in my Application Settings on auth0.com.

However, when I call the `auth0.webAuth.authorize()` method, it redirects me to the following screen:

[image]

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: This mismatch suggests there is a difference in the callback you are submitting and the callback that is registered. Are you including the https:// prefix?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the [Auth0 management site](https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/) you can view the logs of your failed authentication. Then its usually just a matter of adding whatever url you find in the logs to the "Allowed Callback URLs" field of the auth0 application.

[image: Auth0 logs screenshot]

[image: Auth0 log screenshot]